# Decoding 64 in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im using a very simple 64 bit decoder written in javascript to decode and then to *eval* the result:

```
var foo = decode64('eyAiZm9vIjoiYmFyIiB9');
alert(foo);
logUser = eval(foo);
alert(logUser);
```

The first alert fires, the second not. Im getting an error when trying to *eval*:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I don't get it, the foo var has the correct content as the alert shows, attually if you copy the result from a console.log and write the exact code on the console its executes as it should:

[image: screenshot of chrome console]

Im thinking it could be related with char encoding...

Please check this [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ka4r2f0o/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Your `foo` variable is currently a string (not a javascript object).  You simply need to parse it.

```
logUser = eval(JSON.parse(foo))
```

Comment: Actually you don't even need the `eval()` around that `JSON.parse`.